# How to simplify href attribute so I don't get "the given paths format is not supported"?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I get an error

> the given paths format is not supported

but when I use `driver.Title` instead of `links[i]` it works properly, just there is so many same titles and because of that for me its better to use href, but I guess that you cant use ":" or "/" in a file name, so how to simplify href, so I will not get "not supported path" error?

```
int linkCount = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).Count;
string[] links = new string[linkCount];      

List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]")).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
{
    links[i] = linksToClick[i].GetAttribute("href");
} 

for (int i = 0; i < linkCount; i++)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(links[i]);
    ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
    Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
    screenCapture.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(testPath, links[i] +"_"+ testScreenshotTitle),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate url to a valid file name and back to url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423200/translate-url-to-a-valid-file-name-and-back-to-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to get list of links on the page except for a specific links, maybe this would work better

```
using System.Link;

var blackList = {"LogOff", ...};
var links = driver
  .FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]"))
  .Select(a => a.GetAttribute("href"))
  .Where(u => !blackList.Any(s => s.Contains(u)));
foreach (string link in links)
{
  ...
}
```

**Update**

So to sanitize a file name

```
foreach (string link in links)
{
  var fileName = Path.Combine(testPath, link + "_" + testScreenshotTitle;
  foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
  {
    fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: The goal is to make links[i] viable to use in file a name. Like http//:example.com.jpg but I want it to be like httpexamplecom.jpg